# Select child div but not nested

Tags: html, css

Consider this HTML:

```
<div class="row compress">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to target `.col` divs that are first level children of `.compress`:

```
.compress > .col {
  padding: 0;
}
```

This CSS will not affect the nested `.row` and `.col` as planned. 
But if I change the HTML slightly to include elements between `.compress` and it's child `.col` like so:

```
<div class="row compress">
  <div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now my CSS doesn't work because the `.col` is not a direct child.

Is there a way to select the `.col` as in my first example but with the HTML of the second example and any number of elements between `.compress` and `.col`?

As a last resort I could set styles for all children, then override them for nested elements, but this is not ideal:

```
.compress .col {
  padding: 0;
}

.compress .col .col {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I think what you wrote last is already the right answer - I don't see any other way to do it.

Comment: @Johannes problem is then if I add the `compress` class to the nested `.row`, the style will be overridden because of the more specific selector `.compress .col .col` existing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use classes or the following selector:

```
.compress > div > .col {
  /* Your styles here */
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to have any number of elements between the only (easy) solution would be another class.

Comment: Please refer to my part of the question that says `but with any number of elements between .compress and .col`

Comment: @Coop Then you should use then _closest_ parent

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.compress div:not(.row) > .col { ... }`

The trick is to use `:not` css selector to select all direct children of a `div` which don't have class `.row` as inner `.col` elements have `.row` as parent but outer `.col` doesn't have any.

```css
.compress div:not(.row) > .col {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row compress">
  <div>
    <div class="col">Outer column</div>
    <div class="col">
      Outer column
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An interesting approach. The only problem here is if the nested row also had an inner div wrapping it's `.col`. That `.col` would also be selected with your example.

Comment: @Coop yes, but the solution I've posted was specific to the `HTML` structure that you have provided in your Post.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate your answer - it's a good way to tackle the problem, hence the +1. I'm trying to apply this to a grid structure so trying to make these settings global and work for all situations. I did say in my question `any number of elements between .compress and .col`